# failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxx.git'

Tags: reactjs, express, github, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy a ReactJS + ExpressJS app on Heroku, but the command `git push heroku master` keeps failing. I have also tried `git push heroku main`, `git push heroku master:main` and all these 3 after trying to ``git pull`and`git push``` again. This question is not a duplicate of any other, even though the title might suggest otherwise. The project resides on a git enterprise repository

The folder structure follows this pattern:

- the main folder contains the 2 projects along with the .git hidden folder and the `ProcFile` needed by **Heroku**.
- a folder containing the **front-end** - ReactJS
- a folder containing the **back-end** - Express

Contents of the `ProcFile`:
`web: node Server/server.js` - command used to start the back-end server

Script contained by `package.json`: `"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"` - used for building the project on **Heroku** automatically.

Code residing in `app.js`, which is the file that creates the Express app and links the routes. This code should be used to redirect all the requests that are not handled by the backend to the `index.js` of the front-end build:

```
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'),
        );
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: See also https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node